# JS: Array filled with Objects. Can't get numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, get

I got an `JSON` object form a `GET` request. I parsed it, and saved it in an array (where multiple of these requests get saved. Now I got a few `Objects` withing an `Array`.

If I `console.log(myObject[0])` I get this:

```js
var myObject = [{
  "id": "NuB3mw-YV9oo6tZvWB6IW1bFs0xKDDEXTjQ_2M5oN3MpOsM",
  "accountId": "1k022kMktvFQbd4qZ8_FHvaH2xzFwoL85eWtBBrvIYNMtFQ",
  "puuid": "_vHwU3ZEVRAAASNo3O-nmsQBcptlRToANR8EeqW3tAAvagqfUNG_ED6RlnNaS4PGntL-S-OHNGhl9w",
  "name": "AnOnYmOus",
  "profileIconId": 917,
  "revisionDate": 1511281713000,
  "summonerLevel": 115
}];

console.log(myObject[0].name)
console.log(myObject[0].summonerLevel)
```

Nice, so far. 
If I `console.log(myObject[0].name)` I get `AnOnYmOus`

**THE PROBLEM**

now the weird part:
If I `console.log(myObject[0].summonerLevel)` I get `<nil>`

What is happening? I really got to understand this. So far I understand, that **numbers** are an exception in some way.

**Try 1**
I also tried `toString()` them. Had no effect.

**Try 2**
When I make a for loop, everything works as expected. I can get the numbers then.

So why can this work?

```
for (let array of requestArray) { //works
   engine.log('level: ' + array.summonerLevel)
}

engine.log(requestArray.summonerLevel) //but not this
```

Comment: Post a verifiable example

Comment: It not possible. You are doing something else.

Comment: `<nil>` ain't JS. what exactly do you get?

Comment: Yeah, what you're describing works fine: https://jsbin.com/rivihehale/edit?js,console

Comment: I have edited your question to log the level. It seems to work perfectly fine.

Comment: Correct, it's a simplified version of what is within a script of mine.
GitHub: https://github.com/frizzant/league-of-legends-rankify/tree/development (dev branch)

Comment: OK, I had a brief look at the repo. 1. Please always include all relevant information in the question, so it's self sufficient. 2. you maintain a list of globals that get updated rather randomly before continueing and your version of `myObject` is not guaranteed to be filled in when you start using it.  3. You aren't chaining the Promises to ensure correct flow of information between them. Hence the globals. This makes the code much harder to read and maintain.